# Does matplotlib have a maximum number of 2D line plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot many overlapping lines in 2D and I was curious how matplotlib would handle the lines. Is there an upper limit to the number of lines or could one conceivably keep adding plots to the same image?

Comment: I don't know, but I've added dozens of lines to plots in matplotlib with no trouble.

Comment: For those interested, I've plotted up to 33500 lines on one plot with no problem (except for that it looks awful).

Comment: @JadenTravnik, yes I am interested on how you cope with the visualization. I assume you use some transparency. Could you share your code?

Comment: @PA. I wrote this question 3 years ago so I dont have it anymore. Because each plot is different and conveys a different message, I dont think I can help you there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Axes` class contains most of the figure elements such as lines, text, ticks, and so on. They are kept in lists as far as I can see from the [code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py).
So the limit is probably given by how much memory Python has available and maybe some others too, like how long it would take to draw the plot.